# How to add an anchor for a iframe loading tag?

Tags: html

I´m trying to add an anchor to this div:

```
<div class="mosaic-block bar">
<a href="javascript:loadintoIframe('myframe', 'portfolio/optica.html')"   class="mosaic-overlay">
```

My goal is to click this button, load the iframe and then go to the anchor.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can achieve this using html only you have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `loadintoIframe('myframe','portfolio/optica.html#anchor');`? Without seeing how your `loadintoIframe` function works, it's hard to tell.

If the `iframe` is already on the page, then you don't need JavaScript, just this:

```
<a href="portfolio/optica.html#anchor" target="myframe" ...>...</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Kolink. I´m new at this. Ok, the iframe is loaded but the anchor don´t work, the problem is that the anchor is in my main page (index.html) and i want to click that button to load the the iframe (portofolio/optica.html) and then go to my anchor.

Comment: Oh, well in that case you should probably have `<a href="#anchor" onClick="loadintoIframe('myframe,'portfolio/optica.html');">...</a>`